# EXTJS 4 - Decode json issue

Tags: php, extjs

I am facing the problem when trying to create a basic demo of EXTJS,PHP and Mysql.

My folder structure is like this

```
Login:
    +extjs
    +server
        -Connection.php
        -Login.php
    -Login.js
    -index.html
```

This is the content of index.html

```
<html>
    <title>DEMO LOGIN</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Login.js"></script>
</html>
```

Content of Login.js

```
Ext.onReady(function(){  
    Ext.QuickTips.init();  

    var login = new Ext.FormPanel({  
        labelWidth:90,  
        url:'server/Login.php',  
        method:'POST',  
        width:300,  
        autoHeight:true,  
        bodyStyle:'padding: 10px 10px 15px 15px',  
        defaultType:'textfield',  
        monitorValid:true,  
        items:[{  
            fieldLabel:'Username',  
            id:'txtUsername',name:'txtUsername',  
            allowBlank:false  
            },{  
            fieldLabel:'Password',  
            id:'txtPassword',name:'txtPassword',  
            allowBlank:false,  
            inputType:'password'   
        }],  
        buttons:[{  
        text:'Login',  
        type:'submit',  
        name:'signin',  
        handler:function(btn){  
        login.getForm().submit({  
            method:'POST',  
            waitTitle:'Please wait...',  
            waitMsg:'Try to login..,',  
            success:function(){  
                Ext.Msg.alert('Message', 'Login successfully!', function(btn,text){  
                // if(btn == 'ok'){  
                    // var redirect = 'index.php';  
                    // window.location = redirect;   
                // }  
            });  
         },  
         failure:function(response){  
          Ext.Msg.alert('Message', 'Login failed! Please try again...');  
          login.getForm().reset();  
          var txtUser=Ext.getCmp('txtUsername');  
          txtUser.focus('',10);   
         }  
        });  
        }  
        }]  
    });  

    var createwindow = new Ext.Window({  
        title:'URT Login',  
        widht:315,  
        height:155,  
        closable:false,  
        items:login.show() 
    });  

    createwindow.show();  

});
```

Content of Connection.php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "alexpham";
    $dbname = "EXTJS";
    $connection = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if($connection){
        echo "DB CONNECTION SUCCESS\n";
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Database $dbname not found".mysql_error());
    }else{
        echo "CONNECTION FAILED\n";
    }       
?>
```

Content of Login.php

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    include('./Connection.php');
    $username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    $query = mysql_query("select*from Login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';");    
    if($query){
        $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($row>0){
            $response = array('success'=>true,'data'=>true);
        }else{
            $response = array('success'=>false,'data'=>true);
        }
    }else{
        $response = array('success'=>false,'data'=>false);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    echo "\nTHIS IS THE RESPONESE\n";
?>
```

When I run index.html, then type username and password then hit enter. I facing this error in browser's console:

```
Uncaught You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: DB CONNECTION SUCCESS
{"success":true,"data":true}
THIS IS THE RESPONESE
```

Can anyone show what I need to do to fix this issue ?

Thank you so much.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, look at the output generated by PHP: Since you use `echo` to return other information, the resulting output

```
DB CONNECTION SUCCESS
{"success":true,"data":true}
THIS IS THE RESPONESE
```

is not valid JSON. Valid JSON starts with either `[` or `{`, not with `DB CONNECTION SUCCESS`...